# Base minimum WAR configuration

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, war, web.xml

I have a JAR that suddenly needs to be re-packaged as a WAR (don't ask why). It's going to be deployed on Tomcat. I'd like to know what the bare minimum set up is (in terms of the `web.xml` and any other conf files) to instruct Tomcat to deploy the application and run a method that is normally called by the JAR's `main(String[])` method:

```
public class AppDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AppDriver app = new AppDriver();
        app.run();
    }

    // This is the method I need ran by Tomcat at deploy-time.
    public void run() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Since I'm not using Spring or any other kind of MVC framework, and since there are no servlets or need for CDI/contexts, I would imagine that my `web.xml` can be pretty simple; but surprisingly, I can't find anything explaining exactly what I need.

I also imagine I need to annotate the the `run()` method somehow, or make reference to it in `web.xml`. But that's where I'm stuck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of the Servlet spec are you using? For some of them, you don't need a web.xml (they can all be annotation-based).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `ServletContextListener`, in that case when tomcat deploys your application and starts it, your `contextInialized` method will be called, in that method you call your run method.

Then in the web.xml you will add an entry for your class under `listener` tag.

Above approach is for servlet spec upto 2.5

If you are using Servlet Spec 3.0 you can simply add `@ServletContextListener` annotation to your class with no configuration required in web.xml, when your application is started, it will be invoked by your container.

Comment: So if I just list `AppDriver` as a listener, have it implement `ServletContextListener` and in `web.xml` and define my own no-arg constructor, then will Tomcat know to call my custom no-arg?

Comment: Yes, your listener default constructor will be called by tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `AppDriver`  class like `Daemon thread` and start the thread from the `ServletContextListener.contextInitialized()` method.

```
@WebListener
//Use the above annotation if it is Servlet 3.0
AppDriverInitializer implements ServletContextListener
{

   public void contextInitialized(ServletContext ctx)
   { 
      Thread appDriverThread = new Thread() {
         public void run() {
         //Have your AppDriver class run() method implemented here...
         }
      }
      appDriverThread.start();
   }
}
```

Define the ServletContextListener listener in your WAR either of the two ways

- Define the listener in your web.xml

  < listener >
      < listener-class> AppDriverInitializer < /listener-class>
   < /listener >
- If you ware using Servlet 3.0 container, using `@WebListener` annotation

Answer (score 0):

You will need a WSDL if you want outside communication with your webapp.  Other than that, here is a sample web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
  version="2.4">
  <display-name>SemanticAdaptationCoreService</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <!-- You can skip this part -->
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <!-- context-params allow you to pass parameters to your app at runtime -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>param1</param-name>
    <param-value>value1</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- You can provide a listener class to handle WSDL requests -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>your.listener.AClass</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- the initializer servlet allows you to run custom methods when the webapp is loaded -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>initializer</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>your.Initializer</servlet-class>
    <!-- a 1 value requests running the class at load time -->
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
</web-app>
```

Make sure your class extends `HttpServlet` and overrides the `public void init()` method that will be called at load time.